# navigator.serviceWorker.ready never resolves

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I've have witness a very strange behavior on Chrome today... It seems that `navigator.serviceWorker.ready` never resolves after a redirection from another website.

After being redirected, run this on the console:

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.ready
// Promise {<pending>}
```

Doesn't matter how much time you wait... it never resolves.

Now, reload the page and run it again, you will immediately get:

```js
// Promise {<fulfilled>: ServiceWorkerRegistration}
```

Does anybody know a workaround on this?

Answer (score 0):

in my case was situation when pwa installs from subdirectory

`https://domain/subdir`

in this case

`navigator.serviceWorker.ready`

all time in **pending** state but for

`https://domain/subdir` with trailing /
it **fullfilled**
i had registration of sw like

`await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/subdir/worker.js')`;

and change to

`await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/subdir/worker.js', {scope: '/subdir'});`

then for the nodejs added this header:

`this.res.setHeader('Service-Worker-Allowed', '/subdir');`

This solved problem